# How to reduce this array of objects to this one?

Tags: javascript

I need to reduce an array of objects, the reduce function should count the number of repeated objects in the array and set the number as **a value of quantity property** in the repeated object.

```
const x = {a: 1, b: 3, quantity: 1};
const y = [{a: 2, b: 5}, {a: 0, b: 5}, x, {a: 10, b: 3}, x, x, {a: 4, b: 6}]
```

How to reduce y to equal:

```
[{a: 2, b: 5}, {a: 0, b: 5}, {a: 1, b: 3, quantity: 3}, {a: 4, b: 6}]
```

This is my attempt:

```
for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
       for (let j = i + 1; j < y.length; j++) {
         if (y[i] === y[j]) {
           y[i].quantity += 1;
           y[j] = null;
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: Do we need to worry about values?  Is the value of a and b a primary/unique key to they object?

Comment: ok i will update the code

Comment: @Fallenreaper  i only need to abstract the array, it is the same object so we can only refer to the number of repeated object by quantity, i am creating a e-commerce project and i am pushing some product to the cart , i need instead of repeating the product in the cart to increase the quantity

Comment: So, what defines uniqueness of the objects?  You dont want to necessarily do a deep comparison of keys and values, but you can hack it and see if the object contains a quantity property.  I dont think that is a generic solution.  So i figure you would have more insight as to what defines uniqueness across objects in order to allow you to run this against a bunch of sets.

Comment: every product have an id and the comparison can be done like that, if id === id so quantity should be incremented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easier approach, be careful not to mutate data.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-transformation-3?file=index.js

```
const x = { a: 1, b: 3, quantity: 1 };
const y = [{  a: 2, b: 5 }, { a: 0, b: 5 }, x, { a: 10, b: 3 }, x, x, { a: 4, b: 6 }]

const output = y.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(y => y.hasOwnProperty('quantity'))
   // if the first obj with prop quantity is added
   // then just add the current value to the accumulator
  if (index > 0 && x.hasOwnProperty('quantity')) {
    acc[index] = {
      ...acc[index],
      quantity: acc[index]['quantity'] + x.quantity
    }
  }
  else {
    acc.push(x)
  }
  return acc;

}, [])

console.log('output', output)
```

**UPDATE**

Second approach, process of adding a product to the cart

```
// product which wants to be added to the cart
const selProduct = { id: 1, quantity: 1 };
// unique items by id in the car only
const cart = [
  { id: 0, quantity: 1 },
  { id: 2, quantity: 1 },
  { id: 3, quantity: 1 },
  { id: 1, quantity: 1 }
]
// check if selected product exists in the cart
const index = cart.findIndex(x => x.id === selProduct.id);
// if not, add it to the cart
if (index < 0) {
  cart.push(selProduct);
}
// if yes, increment the quantity of the already found product
else {
  cart[index] = {
    ...cart[index],
    'quantity': cart[index]['quantity'] + selProduct['quantity']
  }
}
console.log(cart)
```

You should **never** have multiple products with the same id in the cart and then preform the removal of duplicates...

Comment: smart solution..thank you, but what if i have many repeated objects with quantity property??

Comment: isn't this the case with your example, you provide three objects with the property quantity  with a value of 1 meaning you will get one object with property quantity which is will be 3

Comment: yes your solutions works very well in that situation, but sorry i should have explained my real situation as it is a cart of products and every product have a unique id, and products should not be repeated in the cart, instead the quantity incremented if a product was chosen more than once

Comment: @CodeEagle check my updated answer, I think that this is what you want

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to check each property of the objects without `quantity` for getting a condensed result.

```js
var x = { a: 1, b: 3, quantity: 1 },
    y = [{ a: 2, b: 5 }, { a: 0, b: 5 }, x, { a: 10, b: 3 }, x, x, { a: 4, b: 6 }],
    result = y.reduce((r, o) => {
        var keys = Object.keys(o);
            temp = r.find(q => Object.keys(q).length === keys.length && keys.every(k => k === 'quantity' || o[k] === q[k]));
        if (temp) {
            temp.quantity = (temp.quantity || 1 ) + 1;
        } else {
            r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can this solution be simplified?? especially, the array here is just a demo for a product cart  in my project and each product has an id so we can compare ids,

Comment: if youn have the same object reference (as it actually looks like), then maybe.

Comment: yes thank you i got the idea anyway and i can apply it my self now , thank you your solution helped me!!